# form getting submitted even if validation fails

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where i am disabling the button after submit for 10 seconds and if validation succeeds form is submitted. However, the form is getting submitted even though validation is returning false.

I tried using

```
<input type="submit">
```

instead of image still same issue.

Below is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function enableMe(myBtn) {
                myBtn.disabled = false;
            }
            function doValidation() {
                document.getElementById('hidden1').value = 'true';
                return false;
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="https://www.mySite.com/authService">
            <label for="userid">Username</label><br/>
            <input type="text" value="" id="userid" name="userid"/>
            <br/>

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="password" value="" id="password" name="password"/>
            <br/>
            <br/>

            <input type="image" id="submitBtn" src="btn_login.gif"
                   onsubmit="this.disabled=true; setTimeout(enableMe,10000,this); return doValidation();">
            <input type="hidden" id="hidden1" name="hidden1" value="false"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Validation should be attached to form, not input element...

```
<form id="whatever" ... onsubmit="return doValidation();">
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This works. But my problem is that there are different pages where such change needs to done by client. so, in that case how to get button id(in this case submitBtn) automatically passed to enableme function?